# Removing the duplicates from the object

Tags: php, laravel

Am using laravel5.4,
Am getting the object as 
[
1,
1,
1,
1
]

I want the duplicates to be removed and display the result as 
[1]

How can I do it?
I tried to covert it into array and used array_unique function. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is collection you can try this

```
$collection = collect([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2]);

$unique = $collection->unique();

$unique->values()->all();

//result [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that [1,1,1,1] is a `collection`, you can use the laravel `unique` method in the values of the collection: https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-unique

I it's a plain array, I guess you can transform it into a collection before.