# How to remove duplicates in collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have collection in Laravel:

```
Collection {#450 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Announcement {#533 ▶}
    1 => Announcement {#553 ▶}
  ]
}
```

It is the same items. How ti delete one of them?

Full code is:

```
public function announcements()
    {

        $announcements = $this->categories_ann->map(function ($c) {
            return $c->announcements->map(function ($a) {
                $a->subsribed = true;

                return $a;
            });
        });

        $flattened = $announcements->groupBy("id")->flatten();

        return $flattened;
    }
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993581/removing-the-duplicates-from-the-object/43993750#43993750

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
$unique = $collection->unique();
```

Comment: And if you try: $unique = $collection->flatten()->unique();

Comment: The same situation

Comment: `$flattened = $announcements->flatten()->unique();
        $flattened->all();`

Comment: I have this relations, that returns me duplicates. I tried to use here groupby: `public function announcements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Announcement')->start()->groupBy("id");
    }`

Comment: Yes, but only announcements on which user subsribed

Comment: For actually eliminating duplicate models in a collection, for me it worked this approach:

$unique = $collection->unique('id'); 
$final = $unique->values()->all();

Answer (score 49):

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'iPhone 6', 'brand' => 'Apple', 'type' => 'phone'],
    ['name' => 'iPhone 5', 'brand' => 'Apple', 'type' => 'phone'],
    ['name' => 'Apple Watch', 'brand' => 'Apple', 'type' => 'watch'],
    ['name' => 'Galaxy S6', 'brand' => 'Samsung', 'type' => 'phone'],
    ['name' => 'Galaxy Gear', 'brand' => 'Samsung', 'type' => 'watch'],
]);
```

Then let's say you want the brand to be unique, in this case you should only get two brands 'Apple', and 'Samsung'

```
$unique = $collection->unique('brand');

$unique->values()->all();
/*
    [
        ['name' => 'iPhone 6', 'brand' => 'Apple', 'type' => 'phone'],
        ['name' => 'Galaxy S6', 'brand' => 'Samsung', 'type' => 'phone'],
    ]
*/
```

This is taken from https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-unique

Answer (score 1):

You can unique the data set from the SQL level with groupBy + Max
Try below

```
YourModelName::select(DB::raw('max(`town_short_name`) as town' 'town_long_name'))
        ->groupBy(['town_short_name'])
        ->without('postalCode','country','countryState')
        ->where('town_short_name','like','%'.$townName.'%')
        ->limit(100)
        ->orderBy('town_short_name');
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.