# How to print out all orders with multiple products in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to print out all the orders containing the products. I can not figure out how to build the sql query to return every order once. As you can see it returns the order with id 4 twice because it has 2 products in it.

**Controller**

```
$orders = DB::table('order')
            ->join('customer', 'order.customer_id', '=', 'customer.id')
            ->leftjoin('order_meal', 'order.id', '=', 'order_meal.order_id')
            ->select('order.*', 'customer.firstname', 'customer.lastname', 'customer.country', 'customer.city', 'customer.zipcode', 'customer.address', 'customer.phone', 'order_meal.id AS order_meal_id')
            ->where('order.restaurant_id', '=', $restaurantID)
            ->orderBy('order.created_at', 'ASC')
            ->get();
        if ($orders === null) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return view('/pages/orders', [
            'pageConfigs' => $pageConfigs, 'orders' => $orders
        ]);
```

**View:**
{{ $orders }}

**The inserted data as JSON**

{
    "restaurant_id": 1,
    "customer_id": 1,
    "is_delivery": 1,
    "is_online_payment": 1,
    "meal": [
        {
          "meal_id": 23,
          "quantity": 1,
          "extras": [
            { "extra_id": 10 }
          ]
        },
        {
          "meal_id": 24,
          "quantity": 1,
          "extras": [
            { "extra_id": 13 }
          ]
        }
    ]
}

**Result**
[{"id":**4**,"customer_id":1,"restaurant_id":1,"is_delivery":1,"delivery_price":0,"coupon":null,"coupon_sale":"0","is_online_payment":1,"total_price":0,"is_paid":0,"created_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05","updated_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05","firstname":"Dominik","lastname":"Balogh","country":"Magyarorsz\u00e1g","city":"Szentendre","zipcode":2000,"address":"Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 7.","phone":"06303900000","order_meal_id":**80**},

{"id":**4**,"customer_id":1,"restaurant_id":1,"is_delivery":1,"delivery_price":0,"coupon":null,"coupon_sale":"0","is_online_payment":1,"total_price":0,"is_paid":0,"created_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05","updated_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05","firstname":"Dominik","lastname":"Balogh","country":"Magyarorsz\u00e1g","city":"Szentendre","zipcode":2000,"address":"Vxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 7.","phone":"06303900000","order_meal_id":**81**}]

**Database**
Cutomer table:
[image]

order table:
[image]

order_meal table (products)
[image]

The result shoul look like this:

```
[{"id":4,"customer_id":1,"restaurant_id":1,"is_delivery":1,"delivery_price":0,"coupon":null,"coupon_sale":"0","is_online_payment":1,"total_price":0,"is_paid":0,"created_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05","updated_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05","order_meal":[{"id":80,"order_id":4,"meal_id":23,"quantity":1,"price":1850,"created_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05","updated_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05"},{"id":81,"order_id":4,"meal_id":24,"quantity":1,"price":1890,"created_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05","updated_at":"2020-06-11 22:15:05"}]}]
```

Comment: try to remove duplicates by applying **->unique()** to the collection. like `{{$orders->unique()}}` you can also check this out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169551/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-collection/44169648)

Comment: It is not working for me. An order should have multiple order_meal s, is it possible to get all of the ordermeals as an array?

Comment: is there a same method as `distinct`

Answer (score 1):

**I found a solution!**
You have to set the relations in the models!

**order.php Model**

```
class Order extends Model
{
    public $table = "order";
    protected $fillable = [
        'customer_id', 
        'restaurant_id', 
        'is_delivery', 
        'delivery_price', 
        'coupon', 
        'coupon_sale', 
        'is_online_payment',
        'total_price',
        'is_paid'
    ];

    public function ordermeal(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderMeal','order_id','id');
    }

    public function customer(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Customer','id','customer_id');
    }
}
```

**ordermeal.php Model**

```
class OrderMeal extends Model
{
    public $table = "order_meal";
    protected $fillable = [
        'order_id', 
        'meal_id', 
        'quantity', 
        'price'
    ];

    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order','order_id','id');
    }

    public function ordermealextras(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderMealExtras','order_meal_id','id');
    }

    public function meal(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Meal','id','meal_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
 $orders = Order::where('restaurant_id', '=', $restaurantID)->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
        ->with('customer')
        ->with('ordermeal.meal')
        ->with('ordermeal.ordermealextras')->get();


        return view('/pages/orders', [
            'pageConfigs' => $pageConfigs, 'orders' => $orders
        ]);
```

Comment: The relation in the models is the right and easy way, you just beat it to me to post it